# .ConfigureAwait(false) solves the observation on sonarqube?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, sonarqube

I have this piece of code in a WebApi controller:

```
var task = await Request.Content.ParseMultipartAsync()
                .ContinueWith<IHttpActionResult>(result =>
                {
                    var data = result.Result;
                    var validateImage = new ImageValidator();
                    if (!validateImage.Validate(data.Files["image"]))
                    {
                        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        var newCategory = this.categoryService.Add(new Model.BusinessObjects.Category
                        {
                            Name = data.Fields["Name"].Value,
                            Description = data.Fields["description"].Value,
                            Logo = data.Files["image"].File
                        });

                        return Ok(newCategory.Id);
                    }
                    catch (System.Exception e)
                    {
                        return Content(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
                    }
                }).ConfigureAwait(false);

            return task;
```

The sonar lint tell me to do that to avoid the warning but I don't know what does it mean, is it correct? before my code only has this line:

```
var data = await Request.Content.ParseMultipartAsync();
```

Does the first part of code solve the problem observed by sonar lint?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the issue message raised by SonarLint and its location. In fact, before and after versions of the code wouldn't be a bad idea.

Comment: Why are you using `await` and `ContinueWith`?